# Decoded json file doesn't return whole data in php

Tags: php, json, steam-web-api

After all day trying to find out where there could be a problem, I have to ask.
This is json file I'm trying to decode:
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=4A997F8522CC375E3F9327212B34504D&steamid=76561197996413884

So, I do something like:

```
$url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=4A997F8522CC375E3F9327212B34504D&steamid=76561197996413884";

$json_data = file_get_contents($url);

$json_decoded = json_decode($json_data, true);

var_dump($json_decoded);
```

var_dump returns only 2 inner arrays from 4. To be specific, output is:

```
array(1) { 
    ["playerstats"]=> array(2) { 
        ["steamID"]=> string(17) "76561198007323914" 
        ["gameName"]=> string(15) "ValveTestApp260" 
    } 
}
```

stats and achievements are missing. Suggestions?

Comment: Works fine here, try a `print_r($json_decoded); instead of `var_dump()`

Comment: Also tried this code separately in new file and it works ok there. I'm gonna inspect my code... OOOOOhhh I know whats the problem :( SteamID used in this example above is brothers account. But I was trying to load my data (returned from steam via openid) and I do not own CS:GO. So there's nothing to return. My bad, stupid mistake :(

Comment: So why did it work for me, when all I did was copy your code and run it???

Answer (score -2):

Am assuming u want to collect all data from the url (that is data by GET method `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=4A997F8522CC375E3F9327212B34504D&steamid=76561197996413884`

You should have something like this.

```
$url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=4A997F8522CC375E3F9327212B34504D&steamid=76561197996413884";

print_r(json_decode($_GET));
```

Comment: `$_GET` is an array, the argument to `json_decode()` must be a string.